# Problem in blender when i use the geometry node (random value node)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make a room filled by trash like in this video, when I follow the tutorial I have a different result.

The video → https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M14iZxkUUAQ&ab_channel=CBaileyFilm

To quickly explain the video, he explains how to make piles of garbage with geometry nodes. I proceed step by step, with no problem until here (at 6:45secs in the video). When I add the random value node and plug "value" into the "rotation", the objects I've created are floating, it is weird (see the picture).

I want the same result as in the video, I want my object stuck to the plane. I tried to fix this alone but with no success. But I found one thing when I tried the same thing with the basics meshes like a cube, UV sphere, ico sphere, cylinder, cone, and torus it works like the video (see the picture).

I asked the same thing in the comment section but I think the guy who made the tutorial is busy. I'm new to Blender, maybe there is a simpler way to fix it that I don't know of.

[image: geometry node with basics meshes] geometry node with basics meshes

[image: geomtery node with my objects i've created]geomtery node with my objects i've created

Comment: Because the object's origin are far away from the mesh. Select all your objects, then use Object>>Set Origin>>Origin to Geometry

Comment: Omg big thank you FFeller! It working! Amazing! I'm honestly very embarrassed by this, i knew there was an simple way to fix this it was very easy! Again thank you ! ;)

Comment: @FFeller can you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just to be able to mark the answer as solved, here is a short summary from the comments:

Regarding the *Geometry Nodes*, you did everything right, but the origin of the object is not in the center of the object but shifted.

You can correct this by choosing *Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*.

This will set the origin of the object to the center of the object and the nodes should work as you would expect.

[image]